# Having an issue to create gallery in jelly beans

Tags: android, android-gallery, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am creating a picture gallery for newly android release jellybeans.But i got to know from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html) is that gallery widget is deprecated and they suggested to use ViewPager or HorizontalScrollView.I decided to use HorizontalScrollView to create my gallery.

But after a while i found that we cant set adapter to HorizontalScrollView. Now I am confused how to create my gallery in jellybeans. Help me with your suggestions.Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [article](http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34) and [component](https://github.com/dinocore1/DevsmartLib-Android) that subclasses `AdapterView` for a horizontal `ListView`. It uses recycling, and standard `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`. Note: It does not automatically "snap" to the center view.